# Can't draw on double buffered form

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

In my form class I have overridden the `OnPaint` method

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
    {
        g.DrawImage(player.Sprite, new Rectangle(player.X, player.Y, 20, 20));
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

I have a timer, that does `this.Invalidate()` on `Tick`, and the image is flickering. I've set `this.DoubleBuffered = true` in form constructor, and now my form does not even show anything, and if I resize it, it behaves like this:

[image: 1]

What is that double-buffer thing that I am missing?

Comment: What is the interval of the timer?

Comment: @TimonPost 25ms, to be approx. 40 frames per second

Comment: Although it is not your problem, `using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)` is pointless code. `e.Graphics` is *already* a `Graphics` object; just use it directly. As for your actual problem, the flicker is probably the background being erased. Consider setting `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint` and `ControlStyles.UserPaint`. That may even obviate the need to double-buffer.

Comment: Try `base.OnPaint(e); e.Graphics.DrawImage(player.Sprite, new Rectangle(player.X, player.Y, 20, 20));` - Do not try to dispose thing you didn't create!. Wouldn't you expect the base to overwrite your drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
```

The `using` keyword is the bug in this code.  In essence it killed the double-buffer and the normal painting cycle cannot continue.  Where "normal" is the content of the buffer getting blitted to the screen *after* your OnPaint() method completes.  This screws up *both* the rendering of the background, which is why you see the back of the monitor, and the foreground, the image you drew.

Golden rule for `using` (or calling Dispose) is that you should only ever do that when you created the object.  If you didn't, like you did not in this case, then you cannot assume that you "own" the object and you have to rely on the caller of your code to take care of it.  Which it does, no need to help.

Fix:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(player.Sprite, new Rectangle(player.X, player.Y, 20, 20));
base.OnPaint(e);
```